# distributed interface implementation

Tags: vb.net, interface, class-hierarchy

Is there a way to spread interface implementation over class hierarchy? Consider following example.

```
Public Interface I
    Property X As String
    Property Y As String
    Property Z As String
End Interface

Public Class A
    Property X As String
    Property Y As String
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits A
    Implements I

    Property Z As String
End Class
```

I'd like to avoid to repeat `X` and `Y` in `B`. Think about ten instead of two.
And I don't want to split interface `I` because inheritance of `B` should be implementation detail.

Comment: Use c#. Code above will work just fine if written in c#.

Comment: I fear that. Unfortunately I can't convert the project to c#.

Answer (score 0):

This might not work for your situation but you could use Partial Classes.

This means you will lose class A :-(

Are you using MVC Razor HTML helper classes? I don't think they like it when as interface isn't implemented in a single class.

```
Public Interface I
    Property X As String
    Property Y As String
    Property Z As String
End Interface


Partial Public Class B
    Property X As String Implements I.X
    Property Y As String Implements I.Y
End Class

Public Class B

    Implements I

    Property Z As String Implements I.Z
End Class
```

Not sure how else to tackle this one...

EDIT:

```
Public Interface iA
    Property X As String
    Property Y As String
End Interface

Public Interface iB
    Property Z As String
End Interface

Public Interface IAB
    Inherits iA
    Inherits iB
End Interface

Public Class A
    Implements iA
    Property X As String Implements iA.X
    Property Y As String Implements iA.Y
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits A
    Implements IAB
    Property Z As String Implements iB.Z
End Class
```

Comment: Classes `A` and `B` are already used. I want to encapsulate most of it in the new interface `I`.

Comment: As I said in my question, I don't want to split the interface. In fact you could do this without `iB`.